# Highlight lines in React CodeMirror

Tags: reactjs, codemirror

I'm using React CodeMirror for a responsive text editor in my project. This is what I have right now:

```
<CodeMirror
  options={{
    mode: 'python',
    lineNumbers: true,
  }}
/>
```

My question is, does anyone know if it's possible to add line highlighting by just passing a prop? Maybe something like this?

```
<CodeMirror
  options={{
    mode: 'python',
    lineNumbers: true,
    lineHighlight: {
      from: 1,
      to: 10
    },
  }}
/>
```

This would essentially highlight all the lines between 1 and 10.

Thanks!

Comment: Please check out [react-codemirror2](https://github.com/scniro/react-codemirror2) for usage with React

Answer (score 2):

Take reference to this docs:
https://codemirror.net/demo/markselection.html

and the related code:

```
 <script>
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
  lineNumbers: true,
  styleSelectedText: true
});
editor.markText({line: 6, ch: 26}, {line: 6, ch: 42}, {className: "styled-background"});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you add the ReactJS version of the same? styleSelectedText: true wont work in options param

Answer (score 2):

If using [react-codemirror2](https://github.com/scniro/react-codemirror2) as suggested by [scniro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40825561/highlight-lines-in-react-codemirror#comment80580587_40825561) above, you can utilize the [editorDidMount](https://github.com/scniro/react-codemirror2#events) event prop which gives you a direct reference to the editor. And so a React solution might look something like:

```
const highlightLines = (editor, start, end) => {
  const from: {line: start, ch: 0};
  const to: {line: end, ch: MAX_LINE_LENGTH};
  editor.markText(from, to, {className: "codemirror-highlighted"});
}

const HighlightedEditor = ({start, end}) =>
  <CodeMirror
    value={...}
    options={...}
    onBeforeChange={...}
    onChange={...}
    editorDidMount={editor => highlightLines(editor, start, end)}
  />
```

with `codemirror-highlighted` being the CSS class with the styling you want to apply. Note that the `from` and `to` parameters for `markText` accept a position which has both line *and* character properties. Also, note that line and character are both zero indexed.

*Edit:* If you want to later remove/change the styling applied you will also want to track the `TextMarker` returned by `markText` so you can later call `clear()` on it. If just clearing all marks the editor use `editor.getAllMarks()` and clear away!